# Excel - Conditional sum - 8 values with 8 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

[image]

This table can be broken down to 4 sections (Bank Account, Income, Expenses and Daily Effects on Bank Accounts - as indicated on the top row).

Each Income or Expense comes/goes from/to a Bank Account (assume Cash as Bank Account). For example Expense #2 comes out of the "EC" bank account (as indicated on the right of the value 85).

I need to sum up the daily effects on each bank account in the last section (Daily Effects on Bank Accounts). For example, the daily effects on bank account "EC" will be: +101-646-85 = -630

** + and - depend on, if it is an Income or Expense

How can I write a formula that does that, so that I can paste it on he next rows?

Ideally the formula in the cell on the last row, column 4 from the right to left (AD5 if the table shown stats from A1), will be something like this:

```
= F5 (if G5="EC" else 0)+...-O5(if P5="EC" else 0)...
```

Comment: What part of the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) as you struggling with?

Comment: What happens if you have more than five expenses or more than three incomes?

Comment: I hope I don't have more than that :) or I will put them in 1. I am not sure how to use the SUMIFS function, but I will take a look at it now.

Comment: I looked into SUMIFS but from what I see, it will sum up a range based on several criteria, while I need to add or substract each value based on only 1 condition per value

Comment: I am trying with =SUMIF(O6;P6="EC")+SUMIF(R6;S6="EC") but it keeps giving me 0

Answer (score 0):

=IF(P6="EC";O6;0)+IF(S6="EC";R6;0) and so on...